# why are images returning filesize = 0 when being uploaded?

Tags: php, image-processing, file-upload

I have a php form that uploads files, and all files work good the limit size is set at 7340032 bytes (7Mbs) and it works ok, however when I try to upload an image larger than 500kbs when I echo the values of the first if:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){
```

it says the image size is 0 everytime, why would this happen? the php.ini values of post_max_size is 15M and of upload_max_filesize is 10M.

Comment: Are you sure the `name` on the file `input` is `userfile`?

Comment: Could the partition that php uploads temp files to only have <500kb space left on it?

Comment: Do a print_r($_FILES) to debug.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, yes that's the name, it works well with any other type of file. 
@Fanis, I am uploading to my localhost (using WAMP) and I have way more than that space.

Comment: @Evert I did that and got:

Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => DSCN0477.JPG [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: Error 1 should give you some idea of what is wrong - http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php The file is too large. Are you sure your using the right php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if the uploaded file's size is non-zero is not the proper way to check if an upload succeeded. There's the `['error']` parameter in there for that. An incomplete upload would still have a non-zero size, but should not be processed. A better way to check is:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("File upload error: {$_FILES['userfile']['error']}");
     }
     ... process file here ...
}
```

The error code constants are [defined here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: mm apparently I had to reboot because for some reason WAMP wasn't getting the new upload_max_filesize but what you posted actually helped me figure that out, thanks :)